# Community detection on multiplex networks in R

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I would like to know whether there exists an off-the-shelf R package to perform community detection on multiplex networks?

By multiplex I mean, a set of vertices that are connected by >1 class of edge. In my case I have two classes of edge, and the edges of both classes are weighted and undirected.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Multiplex package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiplex/multiplex.pdf). BR